# An estimate for the solution of an elliptic PDE depending on a parameter

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde, eigenvalues

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with a sufficiently smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. 
We assume $\lambda_1\in\mathbb R$ is the principle eigenvalue of the operator 
$$
-\Delta:\  H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega),
$$
taken with zero Dirichlet boundary condition. Now for any $\lambda\in[0,\lambda_1)$ so that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $L$, the following boundary value problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&-\Delta u = \lambda u + f &\quad& \mbox{in $\Omega$,}
\\
&u=0 &\quad& \mbox{on $\partial\Omega$,}
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $f$ is assumed to be a $L^2(\Omega)$-function, admits a unique weak solution $u_\lambda\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ via Fredholm alternative principle. Moreover, we have the following estimate 
$$
\|u_\lambda\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le C(\lambda) \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$

This constant will blow up when $\lambda$ approaches the principle eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.

I am interested to see that what kind of contradiction will occur if we assume $C$ is independent of $\lambda\in[0,\lambda_1]$ for a fixed $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it lead to an a priory estimate in $W_2^2$ from which by the method of continuity would follow that the problem is solvable for $\lambda=\lambda_1$ for any $f\in L_2$?

Comment: Since $u=(-\Delta-\lambda)^{-1}f$, the bound with a uniform $C$ and *for all $f\in L^2$* would give the same uniform bound on $\|(-\Delta-\lambda)^{-1}\|$, which is impossible because the operator norm of the resolvent diverges when $\lambda$ approaches the spectrum (easy to show, from the spectral theorem). (The bound with a uniform $C$ for only specific $f$'s might conceivably hold.)

Comment: Can the same argument work for the operator $-\Delta + \vec B\cdot \nabla$?

Comment: Here I assume $f$ is a fixed $L^2(\Omega)$-function.

Comment: The same argument works near any isolated point of the spectrum of an operator